# Solving a quadratic inequality $x^2-3x-10>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

I am solving the following inequality, please look at it and tell me whether am I correct or not. This is an example in Howard Anton's book and I solved it on my own as given below, but the book has solved it differently!  I want to confirm that my solution is also valid.

[image]

Comment: Hint: if both x-5 and x+2 have the same sign (positive or negative), their product will be greater than 0.

Comment: Just so you know: "Hay" is properly spelled "Hey" and "Hey Dear" is generally only used between married couples. On a forum, you should introduce yourself using either simply "Hey" or "Hey everyone". On Stack Exchange, you don't need to "Hey" at all, you can just post your problem and your motivation

Comment: Exelent should be excellent. Next time, when you post a thread just say something regarding the question. You don't need to use hey,hi sort of things while posting the question.

Comment: I don't see this is a (differential and integral) calculus question. Why was the calculus tag used?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $ab$ to be positive either

- $a$ and $b$ are both positive
- $a$ and $b$ are both negative

Here, $a=x-5$ and $b=x+2$

They are both positive if $x>5$. They are both negative if $x<-2$. Either of these will solve the problem

Comment: Remove the "non" part in your answer and it becomes accurate; what he has is a strict inequality (">" instead of "≥")

Comment: @J. You are right, I misread the problem

Answer (score 3):

Casebash's answer is very good.

Here is a second answer. You can apply the following

Theorem: If the roots $x_{1},x_{2}$ of $f(x)=ax^{2}+bx+c$ are real and $x_{1}\neq x_{2}$ (with $x_{1} < x_{2}$), then, the signal of $f(x)$ is:

- opposite to the signal of $a$ for $x\in \left[ x_{1},x_{2}\right] $,
- the same of $a$ for $x\in \left] -\infty ,x_{1}\right[ \vee x\in \left]
  x_{2},-\infty \right[ $.

Since in your case $a=1>0$, $x_{1}=-2<5=x_{2}$, you have $x^{2}-3x-10>0$ for 
$x\in \left] -\infty ,-2\right[ \vee x\in \left] 5,\infty \right[ $.

*Addendum:* A possible proof of this theorem is to use the explanation of Casebash, taking into consideration that $ax^{2}+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$

Answer (score 3):

If you graph the function $y=x^2-3x-10$, you can see that the solution is $x<-2$ or $x>5$.

[image]