# Solving the inequality $x^2 + 4x + 3 > 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality, quadratics

So here is the question:

> For what values of $x$ is $x^2 + 4x + 3 > 0$?

So I decided to factor the right-hand side into:

$$(x+1)(x+3) > 0$$

getting:

$$x+1>0 \text{ or } x+3 > 0 \implies x > -1 \text{ or } x > -3$$

But this is incorrect because I graphed the function and I saw $x\not>$ $-3$ for some values of $x$ as the graph dips below the $x$-axis. Where I am going wrong? Could someone help?

Comment: When you graphed $y=x^2+4x+3$ did you notice which points of the graph were above the $x$-axis. Which intervals of the $x$-axis did those points correspond to?

Comment: For the interval: $(-3,-1)$, the function was below the $x$-axis

Comment: If a product such as $(x+1)(x+3)$ is positive, both factors are positive or both factors are negative

Comment: Does this answer your question? [quadratic inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154308/quadratic-inequality). You can complete the square of any quadratic and then use algebra to determine the signs of the inequalities. You can check the solution by sketching $(x+a)^2 - b > 0$ (for example, $(x+1)^2 - 4 > 0$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to consider several scenarios.

In general, when is $ab>0$? This happens when

- $a,b$ are **both** positive, or
- $a,b$ are **both** negative

So, consider: you have $(x+1)(x+3) > 0$. Then,

- $x+1,x+3$ are both positive, or
- $x+1,x+3$ are both negative

In your working, you assume only the former, and get that either $x > -1$ or $x>-3$. Of course, if both are positive, we need $x>-1$, so that gives one solution.

But what if both are negative? Then, when you solve $(x+1)(x+3) > 0$, you are dividing by one of those factors **and therefore must reverse the inequality sign**. Hence,

$$(x+1)(x+3) > 0 \implies x+1 < 0 \text{ or } x+3 < 0$$

when both are negative. Therefore, $x < -1$ or $x < -3$. Of course, again, we see that both factors are only negative if $x < -3$.

Thus, the solution set is the set of $x$ where $x > -1$ or $x<-3$.

Comment: Oh, ok, I did not realise that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Option:

$(x+2)^2>1;$

$\Rightarrow:$ $|x+2|>1$, i. e.

$x+2>1$, or $x+2<-1.$

Answer (score 1):

Since the leading term of the quadratic (of $x^2)$ is positive, it must be concave up, not down.

We can draw a quick sketch:

[image]

and hence $(x+1)(x+3) > 0$ when $x < -3, x > - 1$. When $x = -1$ or $-3$, you get $0 > 0$ which is not true.

Comment: That's also a good explanation, which I resorted to in the end. However, I wanted to solve this algebraically(without using graphs)