# Asking about a bayes Question

Tags: probability, bayesian

It is known that 0.2 percent of the population is HIV positive. A screening test for HIV has a 10 percent chance of incorrectly showing positive when the subject is negative. and a 2 percent chance of incorrectly showing negative when the subject is positive. What proportion of the population that tests positive has HIV?

Comment: This is an exercise in conditional probability and not particularly difficult - what have you tried?  What numbers would you expect if there were $1$ million people in total?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, and where you are stuck, or what is troubling you about this problem.

Comment: If you aren't familiar with these types of problems, see [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Comment: See whether [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4236060/21813) tree diagram helps you understand/solve your exercise.

Comment: @RyanG I claim foul.  I copyrighted the word **Addendum**.

Comment: @RyanG In your cited answer, you used the word **Addendum**.  This is the only time, on mathSE, that I have ever seen anyone besides myself use that word.

Comment: @user2661923 Well, given that I'm the longer-time member, I have a greater probability of being the actual, erm, trailblazer! In all seriousness, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2521/21813) was likely the first such instance. Perhaps you could claim to be the first to boldface it?